# java.io.File.isFile() returns different values in different threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I have some code execution I want to run at a delayed time. (Lets say after 10s). In this code execution I need to check whether the provided files are indeed "normal" files and not for example directories.

```
    for (File f : pAttachments) {
        f.isFile(); // returns true, if file is a "normal" file
    }

    Timer tx = new java.util.Timer();
    tx.schedule(new java.util.TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (File f : pAttachments) {
                f.isFile(); // returns false, even if file is a "normal" file
            }
            tx.cancel();
        }
    }, 10000);
```

What I expected was that the execution in the timer would behave like the outer execution but this is not the case. Is there a reason for this behavior?

Comment: You'll have to post the whole class, so we can see what pAttachments is, but what I suspect is happening is that by the time the time fires `pAttachments` is not what you think it is.

Comment: `pAttachments` suggests you might be handling temporary files representing a mail message.  If that is the case, you cannot expect those files to be available once your handling method returns.

Comment: Yeah it was indeed the case that the files where deleted. I would have guessed that some exception gets thrown if something goes wrong but after reading the documentation this is not the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mikeb and VGR where both right. There was a cleanup step involved which deleted the attachments. I did not come to my mind to check if the files still exists since I assumed an exception would have been thrown by the f.isFile(), which is not the case.

I removed/changed the cleanup so the provided files are not deleted directly. After that the code in the timer returns the correct results for f.isFile().